# Is it possible to change the word "Algorithm" to another word?

Tags: code, algorithm2e

It may be a strange question but I want to change the word "Algorithm" to "Operation" in an algorithm list. I am using the package algorithm2e.

```
\usepackage[ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{algorithm} [tb]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{title.}   
\label{label}

some content 1\\
some content 2\\

\end{algorithm}
```

It will generate the algorithm like:

```
-------
Algorithm 1: title
-------
some content 1
some content 2
-------
```

What I want to do is to change the word "Algorithm" to another word... Is it possible?

In fact, I have some pseudocode to show in my paper, but the pseudocode is short. So it is more like maybe an operation rather than a complete algorithm. Therefore, if the answer is "No" to my question, are there any other suggestions for my case?

Comment: Just a quote from the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) page 17

> `\SetAlgorithmName{algorithmname}{algorithmautorefname}{list of algorithms name}`
which redefines name of the algorithms and the sentence list of algorithms. Example: `\SetAlgorithmName{Protocol}{List of protocols}` if you prefer protocol than algorithm. Second argument is the name that `\autoref`, from `hyperref` package, will use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\SetAlgorithmName{Operation}{List of Operations}{operation}
```

in the document preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}

\SetAlgorithmName{Operation}{List of Operations}{operation}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm} [tb]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{title.}   
\label{label}

some content 1\\
some content 2\\

\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you use `algorithm2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled, vlined]{algorithm2e}



\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Operation}
\begin{algorithm} [tb]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{title.}   
\label{label}

some content 1\\
some content 2\\
  
\end{algorithm}  
  \end{document}
```

[image]